# How can I send large amounts of data using twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, udp, twisted

I am currently building a UDP client server protocol with twisted. I am using transport.write() to send large amounts of data to my client. What I am finding is that only a part of that data is ever sent the rest never makes it. I have read in the twisted docs that not all the data may be received at once, this if fine since I terminate the data with "#endGram#" and have a buffer waiting to be filled. However the "#endGram#" terminator is never received along with significant amounts of data.

```
class listen(DatagramProtocol):

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.buffer = ""

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print(data)
        if "#endGram#" in data:
            index = data.index("#endGram#")
            allData = self.buffer + data[0:index]
            self.proccess_data(allData)
            self.buffer = data[index+len("#endGram#"):len(data)]
        else:
            self.buffer += data

class Broadcaster(DatagramProtocol):

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.loop = task.LoopingCall(self.sendData)
        self.loop.start(3, True)

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        pass

    def sendData(self):
        try:
            Data = self.get_data()
            print(Data)
            data = (json.dumps(Data)+ "#endGram#")
            self.transport.write((data), ("127.0.0.1", 9001))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: I would tell you a joke about UDP, but you probably wouldn't get it.

Comment: Seriously though, one thing to be aware of is your `#endGram#` might not all appear in the same read.  Not saying this is your problem, but you could get something like `foo": "bar"}#en` followed by `dGram#`

Comment: That is a good point, I am better of checking if it is in the buffer. I am printing the data out into a terminal and it looks like only the first part of it is ever sent. I am going to experiment with TCP.

Comment: I have swapped to TCP it works fine.

Comment: Do you at least like the UDP joke?

Comment: I only got half of it and it was in a different order.